# IDK why my code keeps crashing taking the input only one time in this loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

The question is taking input of names of students and their score and declaring the topper but the output ain't working.

Here, I am looking for the highest mark with always keeping the value of the current highest mark, please help me if I am missing something.

```
import java.util. * ;
public class Topper {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    String studentTemp = "";
    String students[] = new String[100];
    int i = 0,
    j = 0,
    temp = 0,
    n = 0;
    int score[] = new int[100];
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter the Name");
      students[i] = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the Score");
      score[i] = sc.nextInt();
      n++;
      i++;
    } while ( students [ i ] != "Alldone");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
        if (score[j] > score[i]) {
          temp = score[j];
          score[j] = score[i];
          score[i] = temp;
          studentTemp = students[i];
          students[i] = students[j];
          students[j] = studentTemp;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The Student with Highest score : " + students[n - 1] + " with score : " + score[n - 1]);
    System.out.println("The Students performance list : ");
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    System.out.println(students[i] + " " + score[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "output ain't working"? Does the code compile? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Btw. the last loop looks weird. I think you've wanted to decrement `i` in there.

Comment: define "crashing", what error do you actually get? do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: `students[i]!="Alldone"` is not the right way to compare strings. And what if you enter 100 things without entering "All done"?

Comment: Yes the thing is throwing some exception!

Comment: I mean your one is also showing and throwing Exceptioms

Comment: its throwing exception just like mine did previously on trying to put the string input 2nd time

Answer (score -1):

Try this

````java
import java.util.*;
public class Topper
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String studentTemp="";
    String students[]=new String[100];
    int i=0,j=0,temp=0,n=0,stop=0;
    int score[]=new int[100];
    do
      {
            System.out.println("Enter the Name");
            students[i]=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the Score");
            score[i]=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue \n Press 0 to continue \n Press 1 to exit");
            stop=sc.nextInt();
            n++;
            i++;
    }
    while(stop!=1);
    temp=score[0];
    studentTemp=students[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(score[i]>temp)
        {
            temp=score[i];
            studentTemp=students[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The Student with Highest score : "+ studentTemp +" with score : "+temp);
    System.out.println("The Students performance list : ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        System.out.println(students[i]+" "+score[i]);
}
}```
````

Comment: you should (at the very least) point out what you've changed, and why you changed it